# How to use associate in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I got next data structure :

```
data class Store (
    val name: String,
    val products: Set<Product>
)



data class Product (
    val name: String,
)

val stores: List<Stores>

val productMap = Map<Product, Set<Store>> = ?
```

How to get a map where a key is a product and value is a Collection of Store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupByTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by-to.html) on every product item of each store to group elements:

```
val stores: List<Store> = listOf(
        Store("S1", setOf(Product("S1P1"), Product("S1P2"))),
        Store("S2", setOf(Product("S2P1"), Product("S2P2")))
)

val productMap: MutableMap<in Product, MutableList<Store>> = mutableMapOf()
stores.forEach { store ->
    store.products.groupByTo(productMap, { it }, { store })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy` after `flatMap`ping your data to achieve it in a single expression:

```
fun main() {
    val stores = listOf(
            Store("Walmart",
                    setOf(
                            Product("Salmon"),
                            Product("Tuna"),
                            Product("Eggs")
                    )
            ),
            Store("Carrefour",
                    setOf(
                            Product("Tuna"),
                            Product("Eggs")
                    )
            ),
            Store("Tesco",
                    setOf(
                            Product("Salmon"),
                            Product("Potatoes")
                    )
            )
    )

    // real work is done only here
    val productMap = stores
            .flatMap { it.products.map { product -> Pair(product, it.name) } }
            .groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })

    productMap.forEach {
        println("${it.key.name}: ${it.value.joinToString()}")
    }
}
```

First, we [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) `stores` in order to have a collection of `Pair`s of `Product`s and the names of the `Store`s. Then we [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) them by the product to associate them with stores where you can buy them.

The output is as follows:

> ```
> Salmon: Walmart, Tesco
> Tuna: Walmart, Carrefour
> Eggs: Walmart, Carrefour
> Potatoes: Tesco
> ```

Comment: Both answers are correct  but https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731626/sergey was first. Thank you.